# React key prop not must

Tags: reactjs

I have a misunderstanding about the PROP key
I manage a list with a delete option
I do not use KEY (or sometimes index name as a key)
And everything works properly even though I expect problems to happen

Answer (score 1):

The `key` prop is used by React internally to track a `Component` back to its respective virtual DOM element. This helps React do minimal component re-renders, which in turn makes your application more performant. From the [React docs on keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity
>
> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys

The `key` prop is not required, but using it with a list will help to significantly reduce the number of times a `Component` list child is re-rendered.

**TL;DR**: Always use a unique key for children of a list (e.g., when using `map` over an array to create components). It'll help React, but isn't necessary for your app to function.

Comment: you mean all work fine without key..and its only for perfomance??

Comment: @philipbrodovsky Yes, the key is just helpful to React to make the best decision in terms of modifying the DOM. Without keys, React will re-build and re-render all of the components anytime the list changes. With keys, React will only modify and re-render the changed components. Hope that helps!